# Get selected value of product attribute onto URL parameter issue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

the result of my script seems to be producing something else than I expected and I cant figure it out after several attempts.

On this [page](http://test.ascension.systems/product/ring-style1-example/?productid=1&styleid=ring-style1-example), you select a Metal & Ring Size then hit the button below. Supposedly my php script grabs the selected values onto the next pages URL which seem to be working but its not giving exactly what I want. Sometimes it works if you go back and reselect, sometimes it doesn't..

It seems like it selects everything that I choose on the dropdown before I hit submit. For example, I select Platinum then change it to Rose Gold. The resulting URL will show both metals.. which is really weird.

My expected outcome: `http://test.ascension.systems/booking-appointments/?productid=2105&productsku=&metal=RoseGold&ringsize=14`

The current outcome: `http://test.ascension.systems/booking-appointments/?productid=2105&productsku=&metal=Rose%20Gold&ringsize=14&metal=Rose%20Gold&ringsize=11`

My PHP script (the script is near the bottom):

```
// Add a custom button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 31, 0 );
function replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // Set below the page ID, your button text and link parameters to pass in url
    $Pickerpage_id = 2100; //Ring Picker Page
    $Bookpage_id = 1277; //Booking Page


    $SPPbutton_text = __('Choose your Ring Setting', 'woocommerce');
    $Ringbutton_text = __('Make an Appointment Now', 'woocommerce');
    $SPPlink = get_permalink( $Pickerpage_id ) . '?productid=' . $product_id . '&productsku=' . $sku;
    //$Ringlink = get_permalink( $Bookpage_id ) . '?productid=' . $product_id . '&productsku=' . $sku;
    $Ringlink = get_permalink( $Bookpage_id ) . '?productid=' . $product_id . '&productsku=' . $sku;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( has_term('Ring Setting', 'product_cat') ) {
        echo '<a href="'.$Ringlink.'" class="book-now button">'.$Ringbutton_text.'</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="'.$SPPlink.'" class="ring button">'.$SPPbutton_text.'</a>';
    }

    ?>



    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('select').blur( function(){
            selectedValue = $('select#metal option:checked').val();
            ringValue = $('select#ring-size option:checked').val();
            hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+'&metal='+selectedValue+'&ringsize='+ringValue);

        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

}
```

Comment: The href property contains the whole URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store hrefAttribute outside from select.blur trigger.

```
<script>
    hrefAttribute='';
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    hrefAttribute = $('a.book-now').attr("href");
        $('select').blur( function(){
            selectedValue = $('select#metal option:checked').val();
            ringValue = $('select#ring-size option:checked').val();         
            $('a.book-now').attr("href", hrefAttribute+'&metal='+selectedValue+'&ringsize='+ringValue);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: when hrefAttribute was inside, in first selecting it was getting hrefAttribute+metal+ringsize value. Then in second selecting you were requesting current(new) value of hrefAtribute instead of first(default) value. That's why it was getting hrefAttribute+metal+ringsize+metal+ringsize.  And in that case if you again chose any of select box, it would get hrefAttribute+metal+ringsize+metal+ringsize+metal+ringsize. 3 times. and so on.